# Making HTML work within JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage http://www.replyonline.co.uk/DirectionGroup/xmas/, and I'm trying to add `<a href="...">...</a>` to some text within one of the of popups.

If you click the first red square, there's an email address there which is what I would like to hyperlink. If I attempt to hyperlink it using HTML, it completely breaks the site apart.

I think it could have to do with the JavaScript starting on line 235.

I add HTML within the Image popup by using this:

```
 // opens one image item (fullscreen)
loadImgPreview = function( $item, callback ) {  
    var largeSrc    = $item.children('img').data('largesrc'),
    description     = $item.children('span').html(),
    largeImageData  = {
            src         : largeSrc,
            description : description
    }
});
```

Notice the `.html()` within this, i think this enables HTML within Image popups.

Not really knowing JavaScript, I am a bit lost with it.

Help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "completely breaks the site apart"? Just change the text `email@domain.com` to: `<a href="mailto:email@domain.com">email@domain.com</a>` and it should work just fine..

Comment: Please refresh the site again. Adding the <a href="... killed it.

http://www.replyonline.co.uk/DirectionGroup/xmas/

Comment: It looks like you're surrounding everything in `a` anchors, which is bad practice for this exact reason. I would suggest changing the surrounding anchor with a span or div.

Comment: Instead of `<a href="#" class="ib-content">` put `<div class="ib-content">` and also change the closing `</a>` to `</div>`.

Comment: How did you hyperlinked the email address? Like this? `<a href="mailto:gingerbreadman@directiongroup.com">gingerbreadman@directiongroup.com</a>` It works for me, I don't know how it breaks, can you enable that 'error' it for a while?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have many [HTML validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.replyonline.co.uk%2FDirectionGroup%2Fxmas%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) in your page for the defined, which is `<!DOCTYPE html>` (HTML 5), be aware of them.

HTML 5 allows both inline elements and block elements (suchs as `div`) inside anchors, but it doesn't allow another anchor inside, and it shows up as an error to your navigator.

Second, navigators automatically fix those errors, so when you add the email link inside the anchor it gets automatically corrected by adding an anchor close tag (`</a>`) before you expect. That explains the mess.

As you're using jQuery to load your items, `$ibItems.bind('click.ibTemplate', function( event ) {...`, my suggestion is to change those anchors `<a class="ib-whatever">` to:

```
<div class="ib-whatever">
```

and jQuery call from `$ibItems = $ibWrapper.find('div.ib-main > a')` to:

```
$ibItems = $ibWrapper.find('div.ib-main > div')
```

Also change **style.css** line 78 from `.ib-main a {` to:

```
.ib-main .ib-image, .ib-main .ib-content {
```

and you'll be working on the right direction.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're site breaks apart when you create the link in the HTML then its going to break apart when you do it in Javascript. The DOM will be no different.

The .html() function in jQuery does not enable html or some such, it is an accessor/mutator for the HTML of an object. What `description     = $item.children('span').html()` is doing is getting the HTML of the selected element, not enabling or disabling any sort of functionality. See the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/html/) for more info on html().

As for your problem, I would suggest looking into why exactly the site breaks down when you insert the link via plain HTML.